# помогите разобраться с async/await C#

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть некая библиотека которая вызывает все методы в фоновом режиме, но я хочу ее переделать так вызовы, чтобы можно было дождаться результата, потом дальше идти. Но не получается. Помогите кто чем сможет)

Вот код WinForm

```
private void ConnectExmo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binanceApi = new BinanceConnector("key", "secretkey");
        binanceApi.Connect();

        binanceApi.refreshTimeServer();                          }
```

вот отрывок самого класса:

```
        public async Task<ServerTimeResponse> GetServerTime()
    {

        var response = await binanceClient.GetServerTime(); //после вызова 
//этой процедуры, все встает колом хотя я ожидаю что смогу получить responce

        return response;

    }

    public override void refreshTimeServer()
    {

        ServerTimeResponse serverTimeBinance = GetServerTime().Result;

    }
```

Comment: `static void Main` -> `static async Task Main` и перед `client.GetServerTimeAsync();` ставьте `await`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а чего не ответом?

Comment: @tym32167 Лень расписывать. Можете ответить, я не против)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вам лень, а мне некогда :D

Comment: @tym32167 Вот и у меня +- также, если не дадут ответ, может распишу как будет время, сейчас максимум могу дать коммент.

Comment: Для этого ответа нужно еще как минимум указывать, с какой версии появилась возможность добавить асинхронный Main, а потом рассказывать, а чего же делать, если версия ниже требуемой.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk Если у вас есть желание - удачи, я не против, ибо это лучший вариант как по мне.

Comment: В чем принципиальное отличие изменений? Все то же самое - надо добавить `await` перед асинхронным вызовом и поменять тип возвращаемого значения с void на Task

Comment: до этого было под консоль, сейчас под winform. и там и там не работает. хочу чтобы помогли, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не следуешь совету :) в первом комментарии тебе написали что на что надо заменить - тут, то же самое. меняешь void на Task, добавляешь `await` перед вызовом асинхронной функции `.Result` не нуден

Comment: не могу я в методе main ставить await. Так как я вызываю метод абстрактного класса Connector, и мой объект не всегда реализуется как асинхронный. Есть реализации  без async. (к примеру new BinanceConnector можно так вызвать а new ExmoConnector нет)Как мне тогда различать?

Comment: где у тебя в коде метод `main`? Что значит _объект не всегда реализуется как асинхронный_?  Заметь, что из-за того, что ты постоянно что-то недоговариваешь тебе кажется, что уже несколько ответов не подходят.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new BinanceClient(new ClientConfiguration()
    {
        ApiKey = "некий ключ",
        SecretKey = "некий secret ключ"
    });
    var task = client.GetServerTimeAsync();
    task.Wait(); //результат будет в task.Result
 }
```

Comment: После того как я вызываю wait() то все зависает. с чем может быть связано. (Если тот же метод при помощи await то данные получает.  т.е. дело  явно в Task)

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов Wait заставляет ждать окончания выполнения таски. Вам вроде это нужно. Если нет, объясните, какого именно поведения вы ожидаете.

Comment: Зависает, потому что возникает дедлок. task.Wait(); использовать очень нежелательно. Попробуйте, может и не поможет:  var time = client.GetServerTimeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: @vusaldev какой еще дедлок, вы точно в курсе [что это](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)?

Comment: А вы? https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @vusaldev ну так вы внимательно прочтите его, у нас тут консолька, если вы не заметили

Comment: только хотел написать, что в консоли отрабатывает норм. Но как переношу на Winform то зависает. про зависания комментарий - относился к WinForm, не думал что имеет значение

Comment: client.GetServerTimeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); не помогает

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов на WinForm такие танцы с бубном вообще ни к чему. в частности, там не будет "почему то он проскакивает все это и завершает программу, не дождавшись". опишите, какую вы задачу пытаетесь решить, но если это WinForm, то и пример дайте с WinForm.

Comment: public ServerTimeResponse GetServerTime()
        {

            var response = binanceClient.GetServerTime();

            return response.Result;

        }
Где  [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<GetServerTime>d__14))]
        public Task<ServerTimeResponse> GetServerTime();
В итоге не могу корректно получить результат

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов отредактируйте вопрос. уберите консольный код, покажите, в чем ваша проблема с WinForm. конкретно по этому коду, просто делаете public async Task<ServerTimeResponse> GetServerTime() { var response = await binanceClient.GetServerTime(); return response; } и... видимо, вы не знаете, что с этим дальше делать, значит, проблема не здесь.

Comment: вроде оформил. Старался чтобы было понятно.